# value by class name not passing to controller?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

```
 <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>S.No</th>
            <th>Part Number</th>
            <th>Designation</th>
        </tr>
       <aura:if isTrue="{!v.FPSdata.Partnumber1__c!=Null}">
        <tr>
            <td><ui:inputRadio aura:id="r1" class="others" change="{!c.sendPN}" value="value1"/></td>
        </tr>
        </aura:if> 
       <aura:if isTrue="{!v.FPSdata.PartNumber2__c!=Null}"> 
       <tr>           
            <td><ui:inputRadio aura:id="r2" class="others" change="{!c.sendPN}" value="value2"/></td>             
        </tr>
         </aura:if>    
         <aura:if isTrue="{!v.FPSdata.PartNumber3__c!=Null}">
        <tr>        
            <td><ui:inputRadio aura:id="r3" class="others" change="{!c.sendPN}" value="value3"/></td>                
        </tr>
           </aura:if>  
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
 sendPN: function(component, event, helper) {
       var x = document.getElementByclassname("others"); 
        alert(x);  
    }
```

I want to send corresponding radio button value to the component controller.

When I click on the radio button it should send the value.

Comment: You are calling `getElementsByClassName` but in fact you are using the `name` attribute rather than `class`. There is no way this script could work with your current markup.

Comment: @AdrianLarson When i use class also it is not giving me the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use `document.getElementByClassName` here because of Locker Service. To get the value/label of the radio button, your `sendPN()` function should be as:

```
sendPN: function(component, evt, helper) {
    var value = evt.getSource().get("v.value");
    var selected = evt.getSource().get("v.label");
    ...
}
```

Take a look at the details of this implementation on the documentation for [`ui:inputRadio`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ui:inputRadio/example).